# channelId, username and tags functionality in API v3

Tags: youtube-api

I am new in youtube API v3 and I would like to ask some theoretical questions that confuse me a litle.

1. The first question is about the *username*, *chanelID* and *channelTitle*. So far I have understand that in API v3 *channelID* is the one we should use in order to distinquish users and not *usernames*. Is that true? If yes this means that each user has a unique channelID by default we he creates an Youtube account? Does the ChannelTitle follows the same logic?
2. The second question I would like to ask is about tags/keyworks that an uploaders optionally attach into their uploads. In the API documentation says that tags are available 
   only for uploaders. This means that we can not retrieve tags for the queried videos through API v3? Until now I could't notice any tag variable into the snippet obtained 
   from *video->list* for some videos I tested. Is authorization matter? In my account YouTube Analytics API, YouTube Data API v3 are enabled.

PS: I am working Youtube API v3 in Python.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Only channelID is unique, user may not have username and channelTitle is not unique.
2. Tags should be available for response. Example here shows how to update tags. https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/python/update_video.py

Mind that you can only retrieve tags (aka keywords) of your own videos.
[More information in the blog post.](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html)

Comment: Hi, I have tried to retrieve the tags of some videos, that does not belong to me, using a Client ID for installed applications in the API access tab but not tag is returned unfortunatelly. Basically, there is no any tag label inside the snippet object. Am I missing something about authorization or the tags of a specific videos are only available to it's uploader/owner? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A have also noticed that in the source code of the pages there is a node named <meta name="keywords"> that contains some tags. Are those the real tags of the videos? If the answer is positive, are all of them or a subclass?

Comment: Metanames and keywords are different. Some videos may not have tags. But I worked out on examples in Java, Phyton and PHP and all returned tags as well as let me update them. I will post a new example on PHP as well.

Comment: Those videos are yours? Can you give me an VIDEO_ID you tested? For example some of the video IDs = {"t5VRiNOnGQE","3kxmKdlnUpQ","3FQDUX6X6-w"} that I tested did not contain tags and I have search in more than 50 videos. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This is the code (http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/930) I borrowed from API v3 and returns the results.

Comment: Basically, I did not understand completely what you mean when you said: "Metanames and keywords are different." 
Maybe I was unclear in my question. I meant that in the source code of the Videos (e.g. id=W2HYQbbe21U ) there 
is a node (e.g. <meta name="keywords" content="the hobbit, hobbit, The Hobbit (2012 Film), the hobbit movie, 
the hobbit tv spot, peter jackson,...">) that contains some info. What I was asking is if these words are the real 
tags of the video. Can you enlighten me a litle more?

Comment: Yes, keywords are known as "tags" in v3 api.

Comment: As far as the tags through API and your aforementioned comments is concerned I can not retrieve tags from videos that did not belongs to me. This means that tags are private for the videos owners or I am doing something wrong?